# How can we get mileage of the car through android app

Tags: android, gps

I have requirement to calculate mileage of car in android app. How to start with this. Currently i am able to get speed through getspeed() method. I can also calculate distance through gps by current and last coordinates. So now i am stuck on the mileage thing. anybody please guide.

Comment: As mileage is expressed commonly as "miles per gallon" or "liters per 100km" or "km per liter", you'll have to ask your user to input the quantity of fuel consumed and divide the registered distance by that quantity.  But to be honest, figuring out a distance traveled the way to suggest seems 1000 times more convoluted than just asking the driver to input both the fuel quantity tanked and the odometer reading...

Comment: Hi fvu thanks for replying , how will the user get to know how much fuel is consumed when car travel a  particular distance?

Comment: You need to know what kind of car they have, or an extremely accurate weigh scale.

Comment: It depends on car usage, a same car will give different mileage count if it getting old. we can't predict the mileage usage.

Answer (score 0):

To get the mileage of the car, user must provide the amount of fuel consumed as there is no other way to get that information no matter how much detail you have about car and journey because a same car may give different mileage depending on various conditions.

For the user to check amount of fuel used, he should know how much fuel he had before starting and how much fuel is left, which is slightly difficult to estimate.

Easiest way to do it would be to fill up a car's tank before starting the journey, drive for some time and then again fill up the car's tank. The amount of fuel that is required to fill up the car's tank for the second time would be the amount of fuel consumed during the journey.